# Need advice on VLOOKUP, LOOKUP or MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vlookup

I have four columns `Name`, `Y/N`, `NameList` and `Result`, e.g.:

```
   A          B              C            D 
  Name       Y/N          NameList      Result   
  Abc         Y            Xyz            N
  Xyz         N            Wto            N.A
  Def         Y            Abc            Y
                           Tow            N.A
                           Wtf            N.A
                           Qrz            N.A
                           Def            Y
```

I want to fill up column D (Result) according to column B if A and C match.
I have tried LOOKUP, VLOOKUP and MATCH but still do not get what I want, e.g.:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$51,MATCH($A$2:$A$51,$C$2:$C$75,0))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are prepared to replace the spaces in ColumnA (with nothing) then

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REPLACE(C2,SEARCH(" ",C2),1,""),A$2:B$5,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(C2,A$2:B$5,2,FALSE))
```

should work for entries in the NameList that include a single space, as well as those with no spaces but you might want to apply TRIM to NameList first.

**NOTE:** Chris Neilsen's solution (in a comment on the OP's own answer) is a *much* better solution (once the requirements were clarified!)

Comment: may i uds what does the 1 stands for in the search function?

Comment: I tried your solution but cant work. For e.g I want to match APL DEN/055W (column A) with APL DEN /055W (Column C), JAME RIVER B/018A with JAME RIVER B /018A. And do i need the IFERROR? i need this kinda urgent, any help?

Comment: I am thinking to make my column A from "/" to " /". But i dk how to implement the replace on column A unless i generate out another column

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to my own answer but it is not the perfect one because it needs to match exactly the same. Meaning the spaces. But i will stick to this first. If anyone has better answer please do advise.

```
    =VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

Thanks

P.S what should i do to also match abc/123 and abc /123. Due to the space currently they are not match

Comment: To handle the possibility of spaces in column `A`, use  `=VLOOKUP(C2,SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$B$4," ",""),2,FALSE)` entered as an array formula (press `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` rather than just `Enter` to finalise the formula)

Comment: @pnuts If Column `C` might also contain spaces use `=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ",""),SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$B$4," ",""),2,0)` (also as an array formula)